# Listview using strings

Tags: java, string, listview

I want to display a `List<String>` in a `ListView`:

```
try
{
  List<String> output = RootTools.getBusyBoxApplets();          
}
catch (Exception e1)
{

}
```

I have tried searching online but have not found anything that seems relevant.

Comment: I have seen this very question yesterday. This is a homework assignment, isn't it?

Comment: Code formatting and added Java tag.

Comment: @ThomasKilian NO I'm self learn developer and developing this app

Comment: Made a few minor edits to make the grammar a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public staticjava.util.List<java.lang.String> getBusyBoxApplets(java.lang.String path) throws java.lang.Exception
```

This will return an List of Strings. Each string represents an applet available fromBusyBox.

Comment: I'm thinking of converting it To array And use array adapter?